# jquery form calculation & totaling

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make form which have 3-4 inputs needs to multiple and get total of each rows. I got this code from Stackoverflow which works fine as far as div are used. But when I change it to table & tr it doesn't work.

```
    <table>
 <h1>table - not working</h1>
                            <tr class="1">
                                <td><input name="pro_qty" type="number" />  </td>                                    
                                <td> <input name="pro_amt" type="number" value="100" /> </td>
                                <td> <span class="total_value"></span> </td>
                            </tr>
<br /><br /><br />
                            <tr class="2">
                                <td> <input name="pro_qty" type="number" />  </td>                                    
                                <td> <input name="pro_amt" type="number" value="200" /> </td>
                                <td> <span class="total_value"></span> </td>
                            </tr>



<td><span class="sub_total"></span> </td> 
</table>



<div>
 <h1>divs - works fine</h1>
                            <div class="1">
                                <td><input name="pro_qty" type="number" />  </td>                                    
                                <td> <input name="pro_amt" type="number" value="100" /> </td>
                                <td> <span class="total_value"></span> </td>
                            </div>
<br /><br /><br />
                            <div class="2">
                                <td> <input name="pro_qty" type="number" />  </td>                                    
                                <td> <input name="pro_amt" type="number" value="200" /> </td>
                                <td> <span class="total_value"></span> </td>
                            </div>



        <td><span class="sub_total"></span> </td> 
</div>




<script>

//any time the amount changes
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=pro_amt],input[name=pro_qty]").change(function(e) {
        var total = 0;
        var $row = $(this).parent();
        var pro_qty = $row.find("input[name=pro_qty]").val();
        var pro_amt = $row.find("input[name=pro_amt]").val();
        total = parseFloat(pro_qty * pro_amt);
        //update the row total
        $row.find(".total_value").text(total);
        console.log(total);

        var sub_total = 0;

        $(".total_value").each(function() {
            //Get the value
            var am= $(this).text();
            console.log(am);
            //if it"s a number add it to the total
            if (IsNumeric(am)) {
                sub_total += parseFloat(am, 10);
            }
        });
        $(".sub_total").text(sub_total);
    });
});


function IsNumeric(input) {
    return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
}

</script>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/triviainc/mt65h25b/)

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using the debugging tools in your browser, step through the code line-by-line as it executes.  Examine the runtime values of the variables.  Where specifically does the behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: @David : Thanks for your prompt reply. Actually I am learning and after banging head for hours I posted it here. But for sure I'll try debugger again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your HTML versions are wrong.

Secondly, when going to table version, you add one more [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) level to get to the actual row.

A quick fix to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/mt65h25b/2/

```
var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
```

Read more about the HTML [table structure](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and **never use a td outside of a table!**

Sadly, your browser corrects most of your code... To really learn how to code, use [DOCTYPE XHTML 1.1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) and give a try to [w3c HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a million for your kind support & for sure I'll keep the things nailed as suggested by you. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Another useful point: try to lower the code indentation in your questions, so that we can read it more efficiently :)